# Why does my program draw all the lines from the top left corner? How to change this?

Tags: c#

I have written a program that is supposed to connect 10 points generated by mouseclicks, with lines.

I am the following problems:

it draws all lines from the top left corner.
I can think of the solution being something along the lines of setting the first point as the first mouseclick, but i do not know how to do this.

code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        Point[] punten = new Point[10];
        private int kliks = 0;
        private int lijst = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

           
         kliks = kliks + 1;
            lijst = kliks;
            punten[lijst] = e.Location;

            if (lijst < 9)


            {
                punten[lijst] = e.Location;

            }

            else
            {

                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue);
                Graphics papier = this.CreateGraphics();
                papier.DrawLines(pen, punten);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pixel coordinates start at `(0,0)` at the top left and go right and down. Did you want the origin to be somewhere else?

Comment: does anyone know how to make the beginning point a mouseclick?

Comment: Use  `Graphics.TranslateTransform(x,y);` to move the origin. But your problem isn't where the origin is, but that you call on `Graphics.DrawLines();` on a fixed size array, and the not yet filled spots default to a point at `(0,0)`. The solution is not to use an array as I showed in my post below.

Comment: Hello, I now understand that the ending point is 0,0. (Took me a few days). Is there a method to make the last mouseclick the final point? I am reluctant to use your other method, as the textbook doesn't mention it, it doesn't function fully, and I have no other knowledge about it.

Comment: You have to crate a copy of the array of points with only the points you want to draw before you pass it into `DrawLines()`.

Comment: I tried this, it does the same thing. i did just make a copy points2 = points after declaring a new points array. it does draw, but with the ending point still being 0,0. if nobody else knows the answer, i will adjust your original answer to draw when there are 10 points, and to get rid of the rectangles. ( i'm doing this for homework..your method isn't what is described in that chapter, but fits the general description of the assignment, i have studied it, i understand it now.. new at coding :))

Comment: If you want to make a copy of the first `n` elements of an array, do the following `copy = array.Take(n).ToArray();`, Alternatively you need to write a loop to copy each element one by one.

Comment: N meaning number? So if I want all 10 points from array mousepoints, I would write copy = mousepoints.Take(10).ToArray();.   ?

Comment: If you want a copy of the full array you do `mousepoints.AsEnumerable().ToArray()` or `mouspoints.Clone() as Point[]`.

Comment: I recommend reading through these [examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/array) of array usage in C#.

Answer (score 3):

The problem for you is using a fixed-size array. Each entry defaults to a point `(0,0)` and so the `Drawlines()` method draws the 10 elements, even the ones not set by mouseclicks. This results in the final few points begin at the origin `(0,0)`. In addition, there is a buggy implementation of which clicks to keep and how many have happened in using `kliks` and `lijst` for the same thing.

This being C#, it is better to learn how to separate your data model that keeps track of your mouselicks and your display codes that draws the lines.

### PointHistory.cs

Consider the following class that uses an array of `Point` to keep track of the mouseclicks. The class is initialized with the maximum number of points to keep (here 10 for example). There are methods for adding a point `AddPoint(point)` and to remove the oldest point with `RemoveFirstPoint()`. The number of points defined is viewed with the `.Count` property.

Finally, the `GetPoints()` method, returns a copy of the array with only the elements that have been defined. This method is used in the code that draws the lines.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class PointHistory
{
    private readonly Point[] points;
    private readonly int maxPoints;
    private int count;

    public PointHistory(int pointCapacity)
    {
        count = 0;
        maxPoints = pointCapacity;
        points = new Point[pointCapacity];
    }

    public Point[] GetPoints() { return points.Take(count).ToArray(); }
    public int Count { get => count; }
    public int Capacity { get => maxPoints; }
    public void AddPoint(Point point)
    {
        if (count < maxPoints)
        {
            points[count++] = point;
        }
    }
    public void RemoveFirstPoint()
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
            {
                points[i] = points[i + 1];
            }
            count--;
        }
    }
}
```

### Form1.cs

Another issue is your drawing, which needs to happen in `Paint` event handler. Use your `MouseClick` event to modify the list of points, and the `Paint` event to do the drawing.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    readonly PointHistory history;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        history = new PointHistory(10);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        this.MouseClick += Form1_MouseClick;
        this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            history.AddPoint(e.Location);
        }
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            history.RemoveFirstPoint();
            history.AddPoint(e.Location);
        }
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        if (history.Count >= 2)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Blue, history.GetPoints());
        }
        foreach (var point in history.GetPoints())
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, point.X - 2, point.Y - 2, 4, 4);
        }
    }

}
```

I have added some extra code to add little dots at the mouse clicks for a better visual effect.

Left button clicks try to add points to the history of mouseclicks, up to the limit set in the constructor for `PointHistory`. The right mousebutton cicks removes the oldest point first before adding the new point.

[image: fig1]

---

Based on the comments, I want to present a version below that does not define a separate class for the logic, and everything is done internally withing the `Form1` class. Also no advanced libraries such as `Linq` are used

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Point[] points;
    private int count;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        points = new Point[10];
        count = 0;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
        this.MouseClick += Form1_MouseClick;
    }

    public Point[] GetPoints()
    {
        Point[] results = new Point[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            results[i] = points[i];
        }
        return results;

        // Alternative to the loop above
        //
        //Array.Copy(points, results, count);
        //return results;
    }
    public void AddPoint(Point point)
    {
        if (count < points.Length)
        {
            points[count++] = point;
        }
    }
    public void RemoveFirstPoint()
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
            {
                points[i] = points[i + 1];
            }
            count--;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            AddPoint(e.Location);
        }
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            RemoveFirstPoint();
            AddPoint(e.Location);
        }
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        Point[] mouseClicks = GetPoints();
        if (count >= 2)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Blue, mouseClicks);
        }
        foreach (var point in mouseClicks)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, point.X - 2, point.Y - 2, 4, 4);
        }
    }

}
```

The main method to look at is `GetPoints()` which returns an array of points that *have* been defined by mouse clicks and ignores any points that have not been defined yet.

There is an alternate implementation commented with uses `Array.Copy()` instead of a loop which would make for a better imlpementation.

Comment: See my updated answer above that uses a `Point[]` array to keep track of the points, inside a class called `PointHistory`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, the only problem is, the course in C# I am taking does not cover some of the things mentioned by you. I could use a class etc, but it is out of the reach of my knowledge. This is a course on the very basics of C#, and this is the last unfinished assignment. I will try the various copy methods mentioned by you and in the link, if that doesn't work, I will attempt this somehow. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @StefanN - C# is primarily an object-orientated language, and classes are a fundamental part of how you build code.  I understand you haven't covered this in class, and in my opinion, classes should be covered on day two of any C# course. In this case, you can move the functionality from the separate class, into the `Form1` definition and see if you can make it work with what you know. Also, understand that the assignment operator `=` for arrays _does not copy the array_ but instead creates and new reference to the _same_ data.

Comment: @StefanN - another edit to the answer in order to address the issues you mentioned.